# 2-col to 1-col responsive design layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to go from a 2-col layout on Desktop like so:

[image]

To a 1-col layout on Mobile like so:

[image]

I am having trouble getting **container #5** to the correct position on Desktop. My markup (modified for brievity) is like so (this can be changed to whatever):

```
<div id="container-1></div>
<div id="container-2></div>
<div id="container-3></div>
<div id="container-4></div>
<div id="container-5></div>
```

On desktop: **#1** and **#5** are floated left, the rest are floated right. But this causes #5 to be position right next to **#4** (#5 top-aligned with #4) instead of right below **#1**. I thought it should've worked. Am I missing something here?

PS: All the containers' height are fluid

Comment: Can you change the markup at all?

Comment: @Torr3nt Yes, you can change the markup. The sample code is just how I have it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the middle 3 in an extra container and wrapping that.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container-1">content content content content content content </div>
    <div id="containerwrapper">
        <div id="container-2">content content content content content content </div>
        <div id="container-3">content content content content content content content content content content content content </div>
        <div id="container-4">content content content content content content content content content content content content </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container-5">content content content content content content </div>
</div>​
```

and the CSS:

```
#container { background: none; float: left; width: 340px; }
div { margin: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; background: #0f0; }
#container-1 { float: left; width: 60px; }
#containerwrapper { background: none; float: right; margin: 0; }
#container-2 { width: 240px; }
#container-3 { width: 240px; }
#container-4 { width: 240px; }
#container-5 { float: left; width: 60px; }​
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GcYuh/

Comment: Lol, that's exactly how I just did it. Thanks! :)